# what is nRF UART and what all I need to implement an nrf UART app on NRF52 DK?

Tags: uart, nrf52

I have an nrf52 board I was able to connect to board via USB. I downloaded a hardware profile to check the functionality and the device acted like a BLE and I was able to communicate with it. But someone said to implement UART on the device now i am clueless about what this is?

there is this nordic toolbox which has UART example but my board won't connect to this why is that?

I wish this NRFtoolbox UART connects to my board how is that achievable?

Answer (score 0):

it will not connect using standard configuration because in this mode it uses pin 5/6 for tx/rx as i remember, and these pins are connected to internal modem, you can not exchange data on these pins. I would suggest to use pins 2/3 for tx/rx.